# How to apply overloaded operators of an underlying type to a wrapper type?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, wrapper

I have a wrapper struct around a container class

```
struct ContainerWrapper
{
   Container data;
};
```

`Container` already has a bunch of overloaded operators defined, such as `operator+`, `operator*`, etc.

Is there a way to "inherit" all said operators without having to manually add them? In other words, can we avoid doing e.g.:

```
struct ContainerWrapper
{
  auto operator+(const ContainerWrapper& other) const { return data + other.data; }
  Container data;
};
```

and instead define some kind of implicit conversion between `ContainerWrapper` an `Container` such that one would be able to readily add two `ContainerWrapper` types together without having to do the above?

---- EDIT ----

I tried solving this with inheritance but it's giving me a type conversion problem.
Here is a following example code:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Container
{
    Container operator+(const Container& other)
    {
        Container res;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            res.m_data[i] = m_data[i] + other.m_data[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
    
    T& operator[](std::size_t i) { return m_data[i]; }
    const T& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return m_data[i]; }
private:
    T m_data[N];
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct ContainerWrapper : public Container<T, N>
{
    ContainerWrapper()
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            this->operator[](i) = static_cast<T>(i);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    using T = float;
    Container<T, 3> cont1{};
    cont1[0] = 1.f;
    cont1[1] = 2.f;
    cont1[2] = 3.f;
    Container<T, 3> cont2{};
    cont2[0] = 2.f;
    cont2[1] = 3.f;
    cont2[2] = 4.f;
    const auto cont3 = cont1 + cont2;
    std::cout << "cont1: " << cont1[0] << ", " << cont1[1] << ", " << cont1[2] << "\n";
    std::cout << "cont2: " << cont2[0] << ", " << cont2[1] << ", " << cont2[2] << "\n";
    std::cout << "cont3: " << cont3[0] << ", " << cont3[1] << ", " << cont3[2] << "\n";
    
    ContainerWrapper<T, 3> contWrap1{};
    ContainerWrapper<T, 3> contWrap2{};
    const ContainerWrapper<T, 3> contWrap3 = contWrap1 + contWrap2; // I want this to return a ContainerWrapper<T, 3> type but it's giving a Container<T, 3> type instead
    return 0;
}
```

The above does not compile because the type of `contWrap3` is not a `ContainerWrapper<T, 3>`, but I want it to be.

Comment: What is the actual problem the wrapper is supposed to solve? Can it be solved through inheritance instead? Right now this is too much of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) for us to be able to help you in a meaningful way.

Comment: Note shown version is most probably broken. `ContainerWrapper` + `ContainerWrapper`  gives `Container`!

Comment: Edited my post with more details on what I want to achieve. I tried using inheritance but the resulting type form the `operator+` is the original `Container` type, not the `ContainerWrapper` type I want it to be.